# How to specify the type of generic class type in Typescript? (e.g. typeof (AppResponse<string>))

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have to specify `type?: Type<unknown>;` in my app.

The interface is as follows:

```
export interface Test extends Omit<ResponseObject, 'description'> {
    status?: number | 'default';
    type?: Type<unknown>;
    isArray?: boolean;
    description?: string;
    a?: Type<string>
}
```

Ideally, I want to do something like:

`type: AppResponse<string>,`

but I can't. The compiler says something like:

`error TS1005: '(' expected.`, which is not helpful.

I have just been browsing Stack Overflow, but could not find anything helpful.

Does anyone know how to approach it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Andrey,

Generics are defined after the interface name using angular bracket notation. Generally speaking, the definition of the generic would use T, U, etc., but the generic could be named anything

```
export interface ITest<Type, AnotherType> {
    status?: number | 'default';
    type?: Type;
    isArray?: boolean;
    description?: string;
    a?: AnotherType
}
```

You would then use `ITest` like so:

```
const test: ITest<unknown, string> = {
  a: "Some String"
}

// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.ts(2322)
const notValid: ITest<unknown, string> = {
  a: 123
};
```

In stead of the second type being a string, you could have another generic definition used there:

`interface IAppResponse<T> { prop1: T, ...props }`

`const test2: ITest<unknown, IAppResponse<string>> = { a: { prop1: 'value' } };`

Comment: It's just the fact that I can do:
`const promise: any = Promise;`

But I can't do:
`const promise: any = Promise<any>;`

Comment: the interface `ITest` is declared for me, I can't change it. I just need to be able to assign a generic class to the `Type<unknown>` type. Which is really hard right now for some reason!